# Why isn't my file opening, C++? XCode and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, input, filestream

This is happening in both Visual Studio and XCode

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream input;

    input.open ("matrices.txt");

    if (!input.is_open()) {
        cout << "not open!";
    } else {
        cout << "open!";
    }

    input.close();

    return 0;
}
```

My file is not opening. The text file matrices.txt is in the same directory.

Comment: if you are executing it inside an IDE the current directory is probably the same where the project file is located (you should check the settings of your IDE to find out where the current dir is pointing to). As alternative you can just open a terminal, navigate to your executable and run it from the terminal (matrices.txt should also be in the same dir)

Comment: The **current directory** (the directory assumed by default for unqualified file and directory names) is not necessarily the same as the **executable's directory**. In fact it's rare that they're the same. For example, when you run Notepad you seldom change the current directory to `c:\windows\system32` first.

Comment: maybe the output of `system("chdir")` would be illuminating

Answer (score 0):

What is "same directory" in this context?

For a file to open like this, it has to be in the *working directory* of the executable when run in the debugger.

For Xcode; this means adding the files to the Copy Files build phase (accessible by editing the executable's target); and adding it to the `Products Directory`, selected from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode if you want to work with a file you have to put it in a folder called DeriverData. You can navigate to it by doing the following:

Xcode > preferences > click on Locations.

this brings up the following window
[image]

you can click on the small arrow to the right of the path: /Users/dulybon1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

It will open the directory containing a list of all your Xcode projects. Find your project and navigate to: build > products > debug

as seen below:

[image]

Then you can put your files there. "a1.txt" and "a2.txt" are files that I have put there to work with. And I think the file needs to exist before it can be opened, so just create blank files if you are planning of using them. Hope that helps